# About Farkle Threshold Score

Tags: farkle

What is the threshold score you would require yourself to have in order to bank with three,four,five dice left? Assume you are trying to **maximize the expected value of this one turn** (so ignore things like how many points you or your opponents need to win).
Rules

[image]

Comment: "assuming you are not aggressively playing" is not sufficient to tell us what you _are_ trying to do. For example, the answer will be very different if you are currently beating your opponent by 800 points vs if they are beating you by 800. Are you perhaps asking what to do to **maximize the expected value of this one turn**, irrespective of everyone's scores?

Comment: yes i mean that.

Comment: Ok, I edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman This is a good edit.  What scoring system are we using?  The us retail version?  I feel as though this game should be solvable.

Comment: And do you play with the "hot dice" rule, where if you bank off all 6 dice you can continue with all 6?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bank if you have at least this many points:

- 3 dice: 450
- 4 dice: 1050
- 5 dice: 3050

**More importantly, you can easily generate complete strategies for any of the common rulesets [here](http://www.mattbusche.org/projects/farkle/settings.php).** (The rules you describe are that site's "Facebook Farkle Scoring" preset, except I changed "triple farkle penalty" and "minimum deposit" to 0 since you didn't talk about those.)

Remember that in an actual game of Farkle you would have to adapt this strategy based on how well you and your opponent are doing and what the winning threshold is.

Comment: Thats a good answer.But can you tell me the threshold scores when triple farkle penalty (-500 points)  and hot dice rule apply and minimum deposit is 300 (like facebook farkle).Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an analysis](http://www.mattbusche.org/blog/article/zilch/) of the game of Zilch, whose scoring only differs slightly compared to the scoring you've given:

- Three pairs scores 1,500 instead of 750.
- You may score 500 points if you roll all 6 dice and have no other scoring combinations
- Multiples of the same dice score 100*n^(x-2) instead of 100*n*(x-2), where n is the value of the die and x is the number of dice in the combination.  I.e. 4 twos would score 800 instead of 600, 5 twos would score 1600 instead of 800, etc.
- Scoring a "Zilch" (a score of zero) in three consecutive rounds costs 500 points.

The first three rule differences will slightly increase the expected value of a roll.  The fourth rule difference can be ignored by only following the Zilch strategy when you have zero Zilches.